# Oracle left join

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables A1,A2
A1 (primary key ID):

```
| ID    |   NAME  |
|-------|---------|  
| 1     |   Cat1  |      
| 2     |   Cat2  |   
| 3     |   Cat3  |   
| 4     |   Cat4  | 
| 5     |   Cat5  |
```

and A2 (primary key ID, foreign key A1_ID=A1.ID)

```
| ID    |   NAME  | A1_ID  |  TYPE  |
|-------|---------|--------|--------|    
| 1     |   Sub1  |   1    |    L   |  
| 2     |   Sub2  |   2    |    F   |    
| 3     |   Sub3  |   3    |    V   |     
| 4     |   Sub4  |   4    |    L   |
| 5     |   Sub5  |   4    |    V   |
| 6     |   Sub6  |   5    |        |
```

I am trying to get all the results from both tables where A2.Type is L or F or null

This is what I have up to now:

```
select a.*, b.*
     from  a1 a
 left join a2 b
        on a.id=b.a1_id
    where (b.type='L'  
        or b.type='F'
        or b.type is null)
```

which returns :

```
| ID    |   NAME  |  ID    |   NAME | A1_ID  |  TYPE  |
|-------|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|  
|   1   |   Cat1  |   1    |  Sub1  |   1    |    L   |
|   2   |   Cat2  |   2    |  Sub2  |   2    |    F   |
|   4   |   Cat4  |   4    |  Sub4  |   4    |    L   |
|   5   |   Cat5  |   6    |  Sub6  |   5    |        |
```

But I am looking for a query that it will exclude the line with A1.ID = 4 because with the same A1_ID there is a row with TYPE=V

```
| ID    |   NAME  |  ID    |   NAME | A1_ID  |  TYPE  |
|-------|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|  
|   1   |   Cat1  |   1    |  Sub1  |   1    |    L   |
|   2   |   Cat2  |   2    |  Sub2  |   2    |    F   |
|   5   |   Cat5  |   6    |  Sub6  |   5    |        |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: left join to the left join based on A1_ID where type is v if a record exists exclude that row.

Comment: did you try a `NATURAL JOIN` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.*
     from  a1 a
 left join a2 b
        on a.id=b.a1_id
 left join a2 c
        on c.a1_ID = b.a1_ID AND c.type = 'V'
    where (b.type='L'  
        or b.type='F'
        or b.type is null)
        and c.type is null
```

This is one way.  If all you ever need to consider is v this should be efficient.  However, if you need to adjust based on other criteria there maybe a better way.

in essence this takes your current results and compares it to another set of a2 that only contains record type "V".  If any match is found, it is excluded from the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `not exists`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from  a1 a left join
      a2 b
      on a.id = b.a1_id
where (b.type = 'L' or b.type='F' or b.type is null) and
      not exists (select 1 from a2 where a2.id = a.id and a2.type = 'V');
```

Your original query doesn't quite do what your text says.  This seems to be what you are describing:

```
select a.*, b.*
from  a1 a join
      a2 b
      on a.id = b.a1_id and
        (b.type = 'L' or b.type='F' or b.type is null)
 where not exists (select 1 from a2 where a2.id = a.id and a2.type = 'V');
```

That is, the conditions in the `where` clause are moved to the `on` clause and the join is changed to an inner join.  The difference is when there are no matches in `a2` for a given `id`.  Your version would return the row.  This version will filter it out.